# Backgroundworkers, Objects created by form designer and how to access them in the dowork thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, clr, backgroundworker

I'm trying to perform a task in the background and I'm using panels created by the form designer but my backgroundworker is not allowed to access them.

I want to use a Array filled with Panels. But I keep getting an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException

When I try to add them to my cliext::vector. Which says that im not allowed to use the Panel because there are created in a different thread.

I tried catching the exception and I tried to make the array static but that didn't work either. Also there was a option to use a Invoker but I couldn't get that to run.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    backgroundWorker1->RunWorkerAsync(1);
}

private: System::Void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    cliext::vector<Panel^> allePanel;
    allePanel.push_back(panel1);//1
    allePanel.push_back(panel4);//2
    allePanel.push_back(panel3);//3
}
```

I basically want to change the color of the panels in the background in an infinite loop.

Comment: That is not code that is ever useful in a worker thread, it doesn't take any work to get it done.  And illegal, you can't touch UI components on a worker thread, as it points out.  Use a Timer instead, drop it from the toolbox onto the form.

Comment: I tryed it and it not working as i want it too.
My Problem is that my gui frezzes once i started it.
Thats why i wanted to use a different thread.
Its a endless loop that runs in the background and changes the color of the panels every 1second. And "normal" threads dont work with CLR so idk what else to do.